# SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally

Tags: django, postgresql

i want run

> python manage.py runserver
> but got this error !!

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "172.16.11.139", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "some_name"
connection to server at "172.16.10.139", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "some_name"
```

i use this article for postgres remote connection

> https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection

what i miss?!

setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.getenv('NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('HOST'),
        'PORT': int(os.getenv('PORT')),
    }
}
```

Comment: What you missed is  the correct password for user "some_name". What is Postgres version and how was it installed? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: What is the real error, the one in the title or the one in the body?

Comment: To make sure if the connection details are valid I refer you to try connecting Postgresql instance with **psql** command line tool, then you'll know if there is problem in conneciton details or connectivity between django and postgres.